# UI best practice for implementing setting with two options

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, interface-builder

I'm creating my settings view in my app with various options for my app that the user can choose from. I'd like to include a setting that toggles  between two options. I've used a UIswitch but it is not representative enough because my two options or not yes or no but customised. (I guess in the PC era this typically was implemented using radio buttons.) It's similar to how under settings app -> Notifications -> sort order you can choose between two options: "Recent" and "Manual".

I'd like to do something similar. What's the best practice for this? Do I need to create a new Table View Controller and set static cells, etc. Just for two static cells? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to in Settings is really just a little tableview with two options. But, as an alternative to `Switch`, I would suggest using a `UISegmentedControl`. This can easily be used to give an option between two (or more) alternatives.

Example use: http://sourcefreeze.com/uisegmentedcontrol-example-using-swift-in-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using of [settings bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Preferences/Preferences.html) instead of your custom UI. If you choose Settings Bundle, you'll get this static table view functionality for free.